# How to describe and work with this specific set

Tags: linear-algebra

What does [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kU6E0.png) set mean?
$$\mathbb Z_5[x]_{x^4+1}$$

How does it behave working with functions?
How do I describe the "general form"?

Would love to look it up on the forum but I'm not even sure how to name this set (or quantity?).

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you could give more context. Where did you see this?

Comment: I found this in my cs math class. Topic are sets and the task was to create an addition table for this specific set. @Michael

Comment: This is not a standard notation.  Possibly the only person who knows what it means is whoever wrote this. My guess is that it means $\Bbb Z_5[x]/(x^4+1)$.